# Unity Renderer.bounds issue?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to make rend.bounds.max.y be always equal to 20 on collision no matter what, using the script below. But it seems that I can't set it manually and the script has no effect on my GameObject.

Script:

```
public class ClassKey : MonoBehaviour{

void Start()
   { 
       rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
   }

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
   {
       //more code
       rend.bounds.max.y = 20;
       //more code
   }
}
```

What I want to achieve: "Change `rend.bounds.max.y` to 20 when colliding (and keep 20 forever), and let `rend.bounds.max.x` and `rend.bounds.max.z` vary freely when colliding"

The problem: Renderer.bounds is read only... How can I go around this?

Comment: As I far as I concern, Renderer.bounds are a result of the position, scale and rotation. What behaviour you want to implement?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change `Renderer.bounds`. You can try to change `Mesh.bounds`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Renderer's bounds in Unity are read only. According to the documentation at http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html ,

The renderer is

> The bounding volume of the renderer (Read Only).

I currently haven't found any way to change the renderer settings in Unity's documentation but I will change my answer accordingly when I do.